# Overloading with constants

Tags: typescript

I was getting some some unexpected behavour in one of my projects so I have isolated it to the smallest example I could that still has the problem. I am using the latest TypeScript build 0.9.1.1

```
module module2 {

    export interface IAnimal {

        colour:string;
    }
}

module module1 {

    export interface IInjector {
        get(className:string):void;
    }
}

module module1 {

    export interface IInjector {
        get(className: "module2.IAnimal"):module2.IAnimal;
    }

    class Injector implements module1.IInjector {

        public get(className:string):any {

            return {colour:"Blue"};
        }
    }

    export var injector:IInjector = new Injector();
}

module module2 {

    module1.injector.get("module2.IAnimal").surname;
}
```

Produces the expected error
error TS2094: The property 'surname' does not exist on value of type 'IAnimal'.

If I swap over the top two modules defs I no longer get the expected error

```
module module1 {

    export interface IInjector {
        get(className:string):void;
    }
}

module module2 {

    export interface IAnimal {

        colour:string;
    }
}

module module1 {

    export interface IInjector {
        get(className: "module2.IAnimal"):module2.IAnimal;
    }

    class Injector implements module1.IInjector {

        public get(className:string):any {

            return {colour:"Blue"};
        }
    }

    export var injector:IInjector = new Injector();
}

module module2 {

    module1.injector.get("module2.IAnimal").surname;
}
```

I actually would like the error to show up to indicate I have made a mistake in the IDE. My question is why is it showing up for the first example but not the second?

Comment: That is awesome brendan. Looks like a compiler error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have done some digging on this. The code is acting as if the `IAnimal` interface was being used before it was declared. You can get similar behaviour by declaring the entire `IInjector` interface in one go, but before `IAnimal` is defined.

```
module module1 {
    export interface IInjector {
        get(className: "module2.IAnimal"):module2.IAnimal;
        get(className:string):void;
    }
}

module module2 {
    export interface IAnimal {
        colour:string;
    }
}

module module1 {
    class Injector implements module1.IInjector {
        public get(className:string):any {
            return {colour:"Blue"};
        }
    }

    export var injector:IInjector = new Injector();
}

module module2 {
    // x is any
    var x = module1.injector.get("module2.IAnimal");
}
```

Perhaps when the TypeScript compiler rolls all of the interface declarations into one it treats them as if they were declared at the earliest location, so you would have to ensure all dependencies were before this point. (Note: I'm not saying this is correct, I'm just saying this is how it is behaving).

Your next move would be to [check the TypeScript issues list](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) and if you can't find this bug reported, add it in so it can either be confirmed as expected behaviour or fixed if not.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Thinking about interface declarations are all put in the earliest location helps me structure my code. This theory holds up for how I have restructured the order of my "/// <reference path=....>". My aim for the above code is to create a simple dependancy injector where I can annotate the interface as I register my concrete classes and include the corresponding type interface.